# What does <# in HTML means?

Tags: javascript, php, html, elementor

I got the following HTML in PHP code:

```
    <?php
    /* First part of a PHP script */
    ?>
            <div>
                <ul class="xyz cat-xyz-<?php echo $settings['post_id']; ?>">
                    <#
                    var allTxt = settings.all_text;
                    var tax = settings.taxonomy;
                    print('<li class="abc abc-active">'+allTxt+'</li>');
                    print('<li class="abc">'+tax+' 1</li>');
                    print('<li class="abc">'+tax+' 2</li>');
                    #>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <?php
    /* Rest of the PHP script */
```

Is this an error?
If not - what does it do? It does not look like valid HTML or JS.

Comment: Could be the delimiters used by just about any template engine / pre-processor. Most of them are configurable. Suffice to say that it is not valid HTML on its own

Comment: @Phil Any idea which pre processor?

Comment: A JS based one probably since the code within _looks_ like JS. Like I said, could be anything if you can configure the delimiters to `"<#"` and `"#>"`

Comment: @Phil Thanks. I agree, but seems that PHP simple script is more appropriate here... Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: You did a god question. I edited your code a bit, because I have the feel people was downvoting it thinking your PHP tags were wrong.

Comment: It makes me think of T4 template from C# (I believe) but it's unlikely to be it.

Comment: My knowledge of PHP is limited; could that be PHP code inside the `<#` and `#>`?  I see that PHP does have a `var` keyword and `print` functions.  You could test this by adding `$version = phpversion(); print $version;` to the code and see what happens.

Comment: @amy  I don't think unless it's a pre-processor I'm unaware of.  `var allTxt = settings.all_text;` is definitely not a php syntax. `$` is missing and `.` (dot) is a concatenation operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer:

> That is because it is not HTML, it's Backbone JavaScript. See
>   [Elementor Docs](https://developers.elementor.com/render-widget-template/)

Added Elementor tag in hope it will help others.